# ¿Cómo establecer el radio button seleccionado por defecto?

Tags: html

Tengo el siguiente código en HTML

```
   <label class="radio-inline">
      <input type="radio" name="movimiento" value="Venta">Venta</label>
   <label class="radio-inline">
      <input type="radio" name="movimiento" value="Renta" required> Renta </label>
   <label class="radio-inline">
      <input type="radio" name="movimiento" value="Traspaso"> Traspaso </label>
```

Y tenga una base de datos que esta cargada con sus respectivos datos, ¿Cómo puedo preseleccionar el checkbox que esta ingresado en la base de datos?
Es decir, si en la base de datos seleccione Venta, ¿Cómo puede aparecer seleccionado el checkbox de Venta?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Para establecer el radio button seleccionado por defecto, debes usar el atributo [checked](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/HTML/Elemento/input/checkbox) :

```html
    <label class="radio-inline">
          <input type="radio" name="movimiento" value="Venta">Venta</label>
       <label class="radio-inline">
          <input type="radio" name="movimiento" value="Renta" required> Renta </label>
       <label class="radio-inline">
          <input type="radio" name="movimiento" value="Traspaso" checked> Traspaso (valor default)</label>
```

El atributo `checked`  puede ser en elementos `<input type="checkbox">` y `<input type="radio">`.

Answer (score 0):

Usa el atributo `checked` tal y como se indica en esta [respuesta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5592370/4092887).

Ejemplo:

```
<label class="radio-inline">
    <input type="radio" value="Venta" name="movimiento" checked>Venta
</label>
```